# Why does my search function only find the email address on the first file it loops through, but not the next file in the loop?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is driving me crazy. This function finds information from one array and puts it into an array with the matching participant. It uses their email address to match. The behavior I cannot figure out is, it will identify the participant in the first file, mark it as identified, and move to the following file, looping through the following file it will not find the same search term in the "data" array. The first search will mark the participant as "identified", so if I run the script a second time it will find the participant in the second file, but not a third file.

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
function searchQueryForFile() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  var participantsArray = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var querySheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Query');
  var data = querySheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (i = 1; i < participantsArray.length; i++) {
    var participantsDone = participantsArray[i][participantsDoneId];
    var registrationSheet = participantsArray[i][registrationSheetId];

    if (participantsDone == 'Yes') {
      var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(registrationSheet);
      console.log(i + '/' + (participantsArray.length - 1) + '-----' + file.getName())
      var fileSheet = file.getActiveSheet();
      var fileLastRow = fileSheet.getLastRow();
      var fileLastColumn = fileSheet.getLastColumn();
      var fileSheetUpdateHeaderRange = fileSheet.getRange(1, 10, 1, 28);
      var headerRowUpdate = [['Identified', 'ID', 'Acct Name', 'First Name', 'Last', 'Active in Term', 'Academic Career', 'MastersDoctoral', 'Acad Prog', 'Program Description', 'Acad Plan 1', 'Plan  Description', 'Subplan', 'Subplan Description', 'School/College', 'Department', 'Age', 'Sex', 'Citizenship', 'Ethnicity', 'Best Use Email', 'UWW vs StateSupported', 'Program StartTerm', 'Prg Begin Date', 'Exp Grad Term', 'Exp Grad Date', 'Current Program Status', 'Degree Checkout Status']];
      fileSheetUpdateHeaderRange.setValues(headerRowUpdate);

      if (fileLastRow == 1) {
          continue
      } else {
        var fileContents = fileSheet.getRange(2, 1, fileLastRow - 1, fileLastColumn).getValues();
        for (j = 0; j < fileContents.length; ++j) {
          var identifiedYesOrNo = fileContents[j][9]

          if (identifiedYesOrNo !== 'Yes') {
            console.log('------------Participant ' + fileContents[j][1] + ' not identified');
            var emailString = fileContents[j][1];
            var val = emailString.split('@')[0];

            if (!emailString) {
              fileSheet.getRange((j + 2), 10, 1, 28).setValues([['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']])              
            } else {
              for (q = 1; q < data.length; ++q) {
                var queryString = data[q][19];
                var queryVal = queryString.split('@')[0];
                if (queryVal == val) {
                  var foundData = ([data[q]]);
                  foundData[0].unshift('Yes');
                  console.log('     Found email in query row ' + (q + 1) + ' = ' + foundData + '--' + foundData[0].length);
                  var fileSheetRange = fileSheet.getRange((j + 2), 10, 1, 28);
                  fileSheetRange.setValues(foundData);
                }
              }
            }

          }
        }
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: `participantsDoneId` is undefined

Comment: Thanks, it's defined in the global variables, it's just a number. It doesn't generate any errors.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the script is marking the participant as "identified" in the first file, but the subsequent files are not being updated with this information. This is because the identifiedYesOrNo variable is only being set based on the value in the current file being processed, and not based on any previous files that may have already identified the participant.

```
function searchQueryForFile() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  var participantsArray = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var querySheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Query');
  var data = querySheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var identifiedParticipants = []; // keep track of identified participants

  for (i = 1; i < participantsArray.length; i++) {
    var participantsDone = participantsArray[i][participantsDoneId];
    var registrationSheet = participantsArray[i][registrationSheetId];

    if (participantsDone == 'Yes') {
      var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(registrationSheet);
      console.log(i + '/' + (participantsArray.length - 1) + '-----' + file.getName())
      var fileSheet = file.getActiveSheet();
      var fileLastRow = fileSheet.getLastRow();
      var fileLastColumn = fileSheet.getLastColumn();
      var fileSheetUpdateHeaderRange = fileSheet.getRange(1, 10, 1, 28);
      var headerRowUpdate = [['Identified', 'ID', 'Acct Name', 'First Name', 'Last', 'Active in Term', 'Academic Career', 'MastersDoctoral', 'Acad Prog', 'Program Description', 'Acad Plan 1', 'Plan  Description', 'Subplan', 'Subplan Description', 'School/College', 'Department', 'Age', 'Sex', 'Citizenship', 'Ethnicity', 'Best Use Email', 'UWW vs StateSupported', 'Program StartTerm', 'Prg Begin Date', 'Exp Grad Term', 'Exp Grad Date', 'Current Program Status', 'Degree Checkout Status']];
      fileSheetUpdateHeaderRange.setValues(headerRowUpdate);

      if (fileLastRow == 1) {
          continue
      } else {
        var fileContents = fileSheet.getRange(2, 1, fileLastRow - 1, fileLastColumn).getValues();
        for (j = 0; j < fileContents.length; ++j) {
          var emailString = fileContents[j][1];
          var val = emailString.split('@')[0];

          // check if participant has already been identified
          if (identifiedParticipants.indexOf(val) != -1) {
            console.log('------------Participant ' + fileContents[j][1] + ' already identified');
            continue;
          }

          var identifiedYesOrNo = fileContents[j][9]

          if (identifiedYesOrNo !== 'Yes') {
            console.log('------------Participant ' + fileContents[j][1] + ' not identified');

            if (!emailString) {
              fileSheet.getRange((j + 2), 10, 1, 28).setValues([['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]);
            } else {
              for (q = 1; q < data.length; ++q) {
                var queryString
```

Comment: Each file is being checked individually against a static list, if it's been identified in a previous file, it shouldn't matter. Your code suggestion also doesn't return any values to the sheet, which is what is being checked for the 'Yes'.

Comment: To clarify, the issue is not with placing information in the sheet once it's found. The search query on a second file says the email is not in the data array, which it obviously is because it was found in an earlier search.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my error by running my code with a simple 4x4 array for both the source and query arrays. My code referenced a location in an array instead of creating a new array with the contents I needed.

```
if (queryVal == val) {
                  var foundData = ([data[q]]);
                  foundData[0].unshift('Yes');
```

The code modified the original array shifting the location of the email address and resulting in the search failing.

I replaced the code with this. I got scared off of using .unshift, but it's probably silly.

```
if (queryVal == val) {
                  var foundData1 = []
                  foundData1.push('Yes');
                  var foundData2 = foundData1.concat(data[q]);
```